# How to create AWS ALB using kubernetes_ingress terraform resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, load-balancing

I'm trying to deploy an Application Load Balancer to AWS using Terraform's `kubernetes_ingress` resource:

I'm using [aws-load-balancer-controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/) which I've installed using `helm_release` resource to my cluster.

Now I'm trying to deploy a `deployment` with a `service` and `ingress`.

This is how my `service` looks like:

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "questo-server-service" {
  metadata {
    name      = "questo-server-service-${var.env}"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.app-namespace.metadata.0.name
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = lookup(kubernetes_deployment.questo-server.metadata.0.labels, "app.kubernetes.io/name")
    }

    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 4000
    }
    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}
```

And this is how my `ingress` looks like:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "questo-server-ingress" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  metadata {
    name = "questo-server-ingress-${var.env}"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.app-namespace.metadata.0.name
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "alb"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type" = "instance"
    }
  }
  spec {
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          path = "/*"
          backend {
            service_name = kubernetes_service.questo-server-service.metadata.0.name
            service_port = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is that when I run `terraform apply` it creates a Classic Load Balancer instead of an Application Load Balancer.

I've tried changing `service`'s type to `NodePort` but it didn't help.

I've also tried with adding more annotations to `ingress` like `"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name" = "${name}"` but then the it created two load balancers at once! One internal ALB and one internet facing CLB.

Any ideas how I can create an internet facing Application Load Balancer using this setup?

--- Update ----

I've noticed, that actually, the `service` is the Classic Load Balancer via which I can connect to my `deployment`.

Ingress creates an ALB, but it's prefixed with `internal`, so my questions here is, how to create an internet facing ALB?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the tf-file installing aws-load-balancer-controller using helm_release ?

Comment: Do you need it for yourself? If so, please ping me in the PM and I'll send it to you.
Edit: you can actually find it in my repo here if you need it:
https://github.com/matewilk/questo/blob/master/tf/k8s/helm-loadbalancer.tf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing` annotation.

You find a list of all available annotations here: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/

Comment: Hey @florianmaxim, thanks for the answer, I figured it out the same evening I posted the question, I just didn't have time to post it. Thanks for your input, it was indeed the `internet-facing` with combination of `NodePort` type for the service.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, like most of the times :)

This is the proper setup, just in case someone come across it:

The `service`'s type has to be `NodePort`:

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "questo-server-service" {
  metadata {
    name      = "questo-server-service-${var.env}"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.app-namespace.metadata.0.name
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = lookup(kubernetes_deployment.questo-server.metadata.0.labels, "app.kubernetes.io/name")
    }

    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 4000
    }
    type = "NodePort"
  }
}
```

And `ingress`'s annotation has to be set as follows: (you can ingnore `load-balancer-name` and `healthcheck-pass` as they are not relevant to the question:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "questo-server-ingress" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  metadata {
    name      = "questo-server-ingress-${var.env}"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.app-namespace.metadata.0.name
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class"                  = "alb"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type"        = "ip"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme"             = "internet-facing"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name" = "questo-server-alb-${var.env}"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path"   = "/health"
    }
  }

  spec {
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          path = "/*"
          backend {
            service_name = kubernetes_service.questo-server-service.metadata.0.name
            service_port = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that you do answer your own questions. :-)